# Mount a volume to a container in WSL for Docker 18.03

Tags: ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So since the release of Docker v18.03 I have been unable to mount a volume to a container in WSL. Previously all I had to do was mount my `/mnt/c` to `/c` i.e. `sudo mount --bind /mnt/c` then just run `docker run -t image_name:latest -v /c/Users/quantik/path/to/volume:/path/in/container` and this would work. However since the release of 18.03 this no longer seems to work. Furthermore, I cannot find any resources addressing this change besides [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly) which recommends creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` file which specifies where your drives will be mounted. This however does not seem to work. I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue?

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: for frontend  Cannot start service frontend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/Users/quantik/app/nginx.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f0733bfec60fc92405b829f5f68463ffe4e94e678651b6ab34f18b24e66a713/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f0733bfec60fc92405b829f5f68463ffe4e94e678651b6ab34f18b24e66a713/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help you but maybe try this:

```
docker run -it -v /c/code/bitbucket/my-api:/var/my-api -w "/var/my-api" centos:7
docker run -it -v c:/code/bitbucket/my-api:/var/my-api -w "/var/my-api" centos:7
docker run -it -v c:\code\bitbucket\my-api:/var/my-api -w "/var/my-api" centos:7
```

For a generic version that will work anywhere

`docker run -it -v $(pwd | sed 's/^\/mnt//'):/var/api -w "/var/api" centos:7`